# Can't populate doctrine embedded document in Elastica

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, elastica

I have an embedded document in my Doctrine ODM Document when I run this command

```
 php app/console fos:elastica:populate
```

I get this Error :

> Object of class ng\myBundle\Document\Coordinates could not be converted to string in /usr/share/nginx/www/project/vendor/friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle/FOS/ElasticaBundle/Transformer/ModelToElasticaAutoTransformer.php on line 139

what seems to be the problem, officers ?

Code from 137 to 141 :

```
if ($v instanceof \DateTime) {
                $v = $v->format('c');
            } elseif (!is_scalar($v) && !is_null($v)) {
                $v = (string)$v;
            }
```

my mapping:

```
 mappings:
                        title: { boost: 5 }
                        coordinates: {type:geo_point,lat_lon:true, boost: 5 }
```

Comment: Show your code at 137-141 lines in `ModelToElasticaAutoTransformer.php`, please

Comment: I don't know why it's trying to convert it to string when I stated that its type is geo_point ..

Comment: You converting `$v` object to scalar `string` type. You must to add `__toString()` magic method in your `$v` object class if you want that it work

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code without `string` converting:

```
        if ($v instanceof \DateTime) {
            $v = $v->format('c');
        } elseif (!is_scalar($v) && !is_null($v)) {
            //$v = (string)$v // if you want that it work, add `__toString()` magic method in `$v` object class
            var_dump($v); // or try to dump var and find to method that you need to call
        }
```

Comment: But then it wouldn't guess the type of field, 
It's no matter for me because all fields are typed 
I'll try that and see what happens

Comment: It will work but will the search work ? 
That's what I'm going to verify now :)

Comment: With `var_dump` you must to dump `$v` var and find any public method that you need to call for convert `$v` object to `string` or to `scalar` value. And then replace var_dump by calling this method like: `$v = (string)$v->callAnyToStringOrToScalarMethod()`;

Comment: but wouldn't this affect my search, I think I just need to declare geo_point in mapping .. but it seems it's more complicated 
Any way , I'm through testing now , and I'll e back with results